# "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file" error when running python program

Tags: python, windows, encoding

Although I included

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the first line of the python file, I keep getting

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\my_project\my_script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I use PyCharm Community Edition on Windows 7. Please help.

Comment: Try `reload(sys);sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` at the start. (It is the same as shebang)

Comment: A hex dump of the first line of the file would be a helpful addition to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file is not saved as UTF-8. Most probably you have saved in some legacy 8-bit encoding (ISO-8859-1 or the like).

Comment: UTF-16 is also a realistic possibility. In fact, a UTF-16le BOM would cause exactly this symptom.

Comment: A UTF-16LE BOM wouldn't cause this. That would error out on `b'\xff'`. It would have to be UTF-16BE, which is far less likely. Your answer itself is likely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I totally understood your question.

But sometimes this can solve the issue:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Or try to open the file by applied an encoding format. for instance:

```
import codecs
 with codecs.open(filename, 'r3', encoding='utf-8') as fd:
     do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

It file is with encoding wrong.
Change it to UTF-8 and try again.

Example in notepad ++:

[image]