# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, syntax-error

While writing the program, I ran into an error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file /Users/user/PycharmProjects/quick_trade/quick_trade/quick_trade/trading_sys.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I tried changing encoding and python path. But it did not help.
I have read several docs but nothing helped.

full code: https://github.com/VladKochetov007/quick_trade/tree/dev

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfe' in file" error when running python program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880439/syntaxerror-non-ascii-character-xfe-in-file-error-when-running-python-prog)

Comment: @Grismar Unfortunately, no

Comment: your problem can be editor or IDE which adds [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Byte order mark) at the beginning of file and adding encoding may not help. You have to change editor/IDE or you have to see if it has option to write without BOM. And you will have to read code and save it again without BOM.

Comment: @furas Thanks, I changed the coding and everything worked